# How to format/include subfigures in AASTex document class?

Tags: subfloats, aastex

I've been writing a document using the basic "article" class, but now I need to change it to "aastex." When I do this, my subfigures do not work. Is there any way aastex allows subfigures?

I tried to keep my original document as bare-bones as possible, so I'm pretty sure caption and subcaption were the only packages I included for this.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
                \caption{Caption 1}
                \label{fig:fig1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.pdf}
                \caption{Caption 2}
                \label{fig:fig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Side-by-side figures.}
        \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Which package were you using for subfigures with the `article` class? In any case, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will be helpful, so we know the way you have the subfigures set up.

Comment: A late note: [`aastex6`](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html#_download) now defines [additional multi-panel figure macros](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasguide.html#new_figure_features) that can help with side-by-side and grid placement of subfigures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's see what a regular figure looks like under [`aastex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/aastex):

[image]

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}
  \figcaption{Side-by-side figures.}
  \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\figcaption` for the caption of a figure. The document class sets the caption flush left (fully justified). Now, let's look at using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and/or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\let\captionbox\relax
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption,showframe}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{fig:fig1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{fig:fig2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Side-by-side figures.}
  \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Letting `\captionbox` to `\relax` makes `caption` work with `aastex` (so it's a requirement). Then, we set the `[figure]` options to ignore a `singlelinecheck` - this sets the figure to be as wide as `\linewidth` regardless of the caption width. Also, a `space` is added as `labelsep`. We also *reset* the `justification` to `\centering` for `[subfigures]`, as they inherit whatever is specified for `[figure]`.

Of course, one can also fake it using `tabular`s (losing some of the cross-referencing functionality):

[image]

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \centering\small (a) Caption 1
  \end{tabular}%
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \centering\small (b) Caption 2
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Side-by-side figures.}
  \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Werner, for the very thorough help! I will be sure to try all this out, but there is still some incompatibility with caption and aastex.

Comment: @ErikaH: For sure! But I didn't see much of that which couldn't be corrected in my example.

Comment: Use `aastex631` and `caption, subcaption` will show `Command \longtable* already defined.` now